# Stop FireFox searching Google with my clipboard contents

Tags: firefox

Occasionally I (presumably) press some key combination accidentally, and FireFox opens a new tab with Google search results, where the query is what was on my clipboard.

This is terrible behaviour in my opinion; I've felt the need to change at least two passwords because of it, but the worst part is that Google isn't one of my configured search engines in about:preferences (only DuckDuckGo is), so it is not what's used for URL bar searches for example.

What is the key combination I'm pressing, and how do I disable it?

I'm presently using macOS, but I'm fairly certain it happens on my usual Linux machine too (I just mistype on that keyboard less, so it's certainly rarer, but I think it does happen).

Comment: That sounds like an extension, I don't think search from the clipboard is built in to FireFox other than right click in the search bar > paste and go which doesn't have a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I certainly don't have any extension that's *supposed* to be doing this... I suppose it's worth disabling some to see or grepping the sources for 'google' though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's middle-clicking on the new tab button (as opposed to the blank space in the tab bar), which according to [this KB page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mouse-shortcuts-perform-common-tasks) is for "Open New Foreground Tab to the Right of Current Tab".

I got lucky and found that the `browser.tabs.searchclipboardfor.middleclick` config flag controls whether it does a search for the clipboard contents.